# Weil Pairing Example fails

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, elliptic-curves

I've been reading about Weil pairing from [Pairings for Beginners](http://www.craigcostello.com.au/pairings/PairingsForBeginners.pdf) and in section 5.1 an example is given. I took a look on the magma code of that example (see [here](http://www.craigcostello.com.au/pairings/beginners/5-1-1-WeilPairing1.txt)) and it works.

All I did was to change the point $Q(21,12i)$ which is in the trace zero subgroup in $3$-torsion to the other point $Q'(21,11i)$ which also is in the same subgroup. Hence the pairing is still non-degenerate.

**Question.** It seems that the pairing is not computed as when we call the function `WeilPairing(P,Q,r)` from magma. Why is this happening ?

You could run magma scripts [here](http://magma.maths.usyd.edu.au/calc/). I attached the modified code (which again is just the point $Q$ which switched to $Q'$).

```
clear;

q:=23;
Fq:=GF(q);
a:=-1; b:=0;
E:=EllipticCurve([Fq|a,b]);
P:=E![2,11];
Fq2<i>:=ExtensionField<Fq,x|x^2+1>;
r:=3;
E2:=BaseChange(E,Fq2);
O:=PointsAtInfinity(E2)[1];
pi:=FrobeniusMap(E2);

//Q:=(#E2 div r^2)*Random(E2);
//(pi(Q)-q*Q) eq PointsAtInfinity(E2)[1] and Order(Q) eq 3;

P:=E2!P;
Q:=E2![21,11*i];
R:=E2![17*i,2*i + 21];
S:=E2![10*i + 18,13*i + 13];

F<x,y>:=FunctionField(E2);

fDBL:=function(P);
    lambda:=(3*P[1]^2+a)/(2*P[2]);
    c:=P[2]-lambda*P[1];
    l:=F!(y-(lambda*x+c));
    v:=F!(x-(lambda^2-2*P[1]));
    return F!(l/v);
end function;

fADD:=function(P,Q);
    lambda:=(Q[2]-P[2])/(Q[1]-P[1]);
    c:=P[2]-lambda*P[1];
    l:=F!(y-(lambda*x+c));
    v:=F!(x-(lambda^2-P[1]-P[2]));
    return F!(l/v);
end function;

f3P:=fDBL(P)*(x-P[1]);
lPR:=fADD(P,R);
f3PR:=f3P/lPR^3;
f3Q:=fDBL(Q)*(x-Q[1]);
lQS:=fADD(Q,S);
f3QS:=f3Q/lQS^3;


f3PR(Q+S)*f3QS(R)/(f3PR(S)*f3QS(P+R));
WeilPairing(P,Q,r);
WeilPairing(2*P,Q,r);
WeilPairing(P,2*Q,r);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the author made a mistake in code.

In fADD function the vertical line equation should be computed as

`v:=F!(x-(lambda^2-P[1]-Q[1]));` instead of `v:=F!(x-(lambda^2-P[1]-P[2]));`

And now works with any points $P$ and $Q$ as expected.